# Audience manager - Com.Tridion.Broker.StorageException: Transaction rolled back

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Edit - Should add this is for Tridion 2011 SP1

When attempting to save a new audience manager profile using the TOM.NET API, I receive the following error:

```
Com.Tridion.Broker.StorageException: Transaction rolled back, error executing work, error executing work
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallVoid(JavaProxy jpo, Object val)
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Profile.Contact.Save(String pageUri)
```

Usually with Storage Exceptions I keep thinking there is something wrong with my cd_licenses.xml file on my presentation server, or configuration doesn't seem to be pointing at it....but I've checked over both and everything appears to be ok.

Anyone come across this message before when saving audience manager profiles?

Comment: the storage exception is mentioning the transaction being rolled back, just thinking is there anything in your database log file which might be related?

Comment: good suggestion, I'll take a look. Something I've noticed as well is that Outbound Email synchronisation isn't working - which could mean an issue connecting to the database (I'm hoping :) )

Answer (score 3):

Possible causes for this problem that I've seen:

1. You're missing some JAR files that are needed
2. You're using the 32-bit version of the DLLs on a 64-bit system (or vice versa)
3. Having Outbound Email and Content Delivery in the same application pool

Comment: The DLLs should be fine, we're operating on a 64-bit environment and did initially have the 32 bit DLLs installed resulting in an Image Format exception, we swapped these out and solved that issue. JARs look ok on first pass and match up with what we have on our other test machine, but I'll double check to be sure

Comment: I just remembered a third reason, which may well be what you have (given your mention of Outbound Email). I don't remember the details (am hoping for someone more experience in OE to answer that), but there were some issues (in 2011 GA) when you loaded both the CD and OE DLLs into the same application pool.

Comment: Also, check your cd_storage_conf.xml to see you have storage bindings included <StorageBindings><Bundle src="AudienceManagerDAOBundle.xml"/>           </StorageBindings>, DB Storage and you have item TypeMappings for AudienceManagerProfile.

Comment: My money is on a faulty storage configuration too.

Comment: In that case: @Ram can you provide your comment as a separate answer? That way it can get its own votes and be accepted (if it is indeed the solution to Richard's problem).

Answer (score 2):

Check your cd_stroage_conf.xml to make sure you have correct storage bindings included.

```xml
<StorageBindings>
    <Bundle src="AudienceManagerDAOBundle.xml"/>
</StorageBindings>

<Storage Id="profiledb" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Type="persistence"
         dialect="MSSQL">
    <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost"/>
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="tridion_submgmt_DB"/>
        <Property Name="user" Value="username"/>
        <Property Name="password" Value="password"/>
    </DataSource>
</Storage>
```

Also, you need to have item typemapping to the same DB.

```xml
<Item typeMapping="AudienceManagerProfile" storageId="profiledb"/>
```

Optionally, if you are using tracking you should have the tracking db and tracking typemapping as well.